# MySQL - optimize query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I don't know how to more optimize this query

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  `job_offer` AS `o`
    WHERE  o.`status` = 1
      AND  EXISTS
      ( SELECT  1
            FROM  `job_offer_localitymap` AS lm
            WHERE  lm.`job_offerid` = o.`job_offerid`
              AND  lm.`gps_localityid` IN (116, 1) 
      )
```

Explain as image here: http://postimg.org/image/52wd06f3f/full/

It's simple select with subquery and it runs about 52 miliseconds on localhost, which is too much. There are many more records server and it runs 350miliseconds there. I also try this query replaced with inner join and group by with same results.

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(DISTINCT(o.job_offerid)) 
    FROM `job_offer` AS `o` 
    INNER JOIN `job_offer_localitymap` AS lm ON lm.job_offerid = o.`job_offerid` 
        AND lm.`gps_localityid` IN (116, 1)
    WHERE (o.`status` = 1)
```

Explain as image here: http://postimg.org/image/3renvl3gx/full/

I just don't get it why is that such a problem.

STATS: count returns 1415 rows, job_offer has 65k rows, job_offer_locality_map has 100k rows. All tables are MyISAM.

Thank you for suggestions.

Here is database dump (table job_offer has many rows - about 50-60, so I give here simple version)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `job_offer`;
CREATE TABLE `job_offer` (
  `job_offerid` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sequence` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence_desc` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_updated_when` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_offerid`),
  KEY `active_updated_when` (`active_updated_when`),
  KEY `status_sequence_desc_active_updated_when_job_offerid` (`status`,`sequence_desc`,`active_updated_when`,`job_offerid`),
  KEY `status_job_offerid` (`status`,`job_offerid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `job_offer_localitymap`;
CREATE TABLE `job_offer_localitymap` (
  `job_offer_localitymapid` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `old_id` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gps_localityid` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `job_offerid` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `old_localityid` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_offer_localitymapid`),
  KEY `job_offerid_gps_localityid` (`job_offerid`,`gps_localityid`),
  KEY `job_offerid` (`job_offerid`),
  KEY `gps_localityid` (`gps_localityid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Interesting the indexes are picking up pretty well and the one as I mentioned in the answer ! Now thats pretty weird, it could be some I/O issue but hard to predict, however I am deleting the answer since it will not help in this case.

Comment: Thank you for deleting inappropriate answers. I debug this query straight from Adminer (something like phpmyadmin) to avoid php libraries in project.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(job_offered, gps_localityid)
```

Show us the `JOIN` version, together with its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`